# Edit the "New Contact" page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, edit

i am not a developer and am looking for a way to edit the fields that are shown on the "New contact page". When users add new Contacts they use the below page to create them, one of the fields that is completed is "Lead Source" which sits on the Enquiry object. When a new Contact is created it automatically creates a new enquiry.

I would like to take the "Lead Source" field out and replace it with some different fields that need adding to the enquiry created. Can anyone help me with this ?

[image: New Contact Page]

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that the standard New button has been overridden with some custom component (guessing LWC). Go to Setup -> Object Manager -> Contact -> Buttons, Links and Actions -> Row containing the New button -> Options -> Edit.

You can see if it was overridden on the list of the buttons or directly in the Edit section. If it was overridden, your only option is to make changes to the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Page Layout for the Contact Object from the Object Manager menu in Setup. You should check the Page Assignments to ensure you are editing the correct Page Layout (if there is more than one layout).

Once on the Edit page, you can add and remove fields as needed from the layout - just remember to click save once you have completed your changes.

The Salesforce Trailhead site has a similar module on editing the Page Layout on Account - perhaps reviewing the steps for this might help you with the Contact object.

Trailhead Link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/create-account-page-layouts

Comment: Thank you for your response. This link only seems to outline how to edit standard page layouts. The page i am referring to and have added an image of is not a standard Contact page layout it is a screen that appears when clicking New contact and brings up select fields to start the contact creation process it is not the full Contact page layout. Any ideas on this ? Were you able to see the screenshot that i added to the post ?

Comment: Is that the standard Global Action for creating a new Contact? If so, then you can edit the page displayed by doing the following:

1. Go to Setup => Go to Global Actions
2. Look for the Action "New Contact" - Click Layout next to the Action
3. Add/Remove the fields as needed and click save

Comment: I don't think it is, i went in to the global actions as suggested and the New Contact global action did not have the fields that are outlined here. Maybe its a visualforce page created by the person previously here ? Is there anyway to identify the name of the page while in the page itself ??

Comment: If it's a VF page then the name of the page should appear in the URL. Is there any clues on the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere I see, the person is asking to edit the new contact form and people are replying editing the Contact Object Layout. At least understand the question please.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! By "everywhere" & "people" it seems you are referring singularly to *@cg133* - the only user to try to answer. The questioner pointed out in the comments under the other answer that *cg133* had misunderstood. So *cg133* did come to understand the question. (Then there was more exchange at which point *cg133* asked a question in order to help further, but the OP never replied.) Your contribution is even less helpful than an answer to the wrong question & is completely unnecessary. At least answer the question if you are going to make snarky comments.

Comment: SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the note about "commentary on the question or other answers" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted.